# How to invoke HTTP request to Mutual SSL(massl) enabled Server using angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, mutual-authentication

I am trying to call GET request to the server which is Mutual SSL enabled using angular 6. But I am getting 400 - Bad Request.

I added certificate in postman and tested the same url ,it worked.

Does anyone tell me how to pass certificate through request.

Comment: Can you open dev tools and C&P the request/response.

Comment: The reason behind this issue was,we are not enabling invoking of Mutual SSL  enabled URL through user interface,due to this I was getting this error.